# Making an AJAX POST to a class based view

Tags: ajax, django, django-class-based-views

I have a class based view that displays a page and handles POST requests, like so:

```
 class citywall (View):


        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            template_name = 'citywall.html'
            city_slug = kwargs['city_slug']
            context = self.get_context_data(city_slug)
            return render_to_response(template_name, context, RequestContext(request))



        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):       



            if request.is_ajax:                        
                if request.POST.has_key('comment'):
                        #process comment
                        ...
                if request.POST.has_key('vote'):
                        #process vote

                      ...
```

The problem is when I try to POST the form with AJAX, two requests are being sent. The Ajax request and then a regular POST request.

This is my comment form in html:

```
<form class="comment_form" data-id="{{post.id}}" method="POST" >{% csrf_token %}
   <textarea  rows = "1"  name="comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a comment..." ></textarea>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Go!</button>
</form>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
var comment_form = $('.comment_form')
   comment_form.submit(function(){

   var post_id = $(this).data('id');
   var comment = $(this).find('textarea[name="comment"]').val();
   $.ajax({
            url: "",
            dataType:"json",
            type:"POST",
            data:{

              comment: comment,
              post_id: post_id,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken:'{{csrf_token}}',
            },
            success:function(json)
            {

               alert(json);


            },

        });     
 });
```

When I submit the form this is happening:

1. AJAX POST is made with its json `data`(post_id, comment, csrf).
2. Response for the AJAX post is received back in browser.
3. POST is made with html `form data`(comment and csrf).

why is a second POST being made?

I have several types of forms on the page for example. comment form, voting form, etc and I want to make all of them AJAX. Is it a good idea to implement all of them with the above mentioned method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second `POST` with your form data is sent because your `submit` event handler doesn't return `False`. If you want to prevent the form from submitting when clicking the submit button, you have to return `False` in the event handler. The event handler can also be told to prevent form submission by calling `e.preventDefault()` on the event object that is being passed to the `submit` handler.

The reason for this behaviour is that, by default, the event fired when a submit button is clicked submits the forms at the very end of the event handling chain. So what happens is that in your event handler you are send a `AJAX POST` call (which is asynchronous), and the very next moment the handler returns without prevent the event from form submission. This results in both `AJAX` and `form` being sent.

`e.preventDefault()` tells the event `e` to avoid doing the default action specific to this event, in this case form submission. With this added, when `$.ajax` finishes and all the handlers are done handling the event the default handler is checked if it's allowed to be run. Since you have prevented it, nothing happens.

The very same method can be used to, e.g. prevent the webpage following a link `<a>` when clicked.

Comment: The second `POST`request is still being made. I think it is because of the `post method`, it is forcing the second request.

Comment: @HHH, try adding an `e` argument to the event handler (`function(e)`), and calling `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: It works! whats was happening? I thought it was because of the `post method`, could you please explain?

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. Is this an efficient method ? because I have many forms and I am thinking of using this method on all of them for making AJAX requests. Once again thank you.

Comment: @HHH, I don't think that the overhead of having a form element in the DOM is that great, and in any other way you'd need to call `e.preventDefault()` unless you'd want to make `<span>` or similar elements act like submit buttons. Another plus is that it might work for browsers with javascript disabled (possible extremely rare case nowadays).